# Zend Framework autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework, autocomplete

I have problem with autocomplete. My jQuery version is 1.11.0.min, jquery ui is 1.9.1.min and ajax autocomplete for jQuery is 1.2.7. That is my jquery code:

```
$(function () {
                $('.client').autocomplete({
                    source: 'ajax/getusers',
                    minLength: 2,
                    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                    }
                });

            });
```

That is my ajax/getusers action:

```
class AjaxController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

public function init() {
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
}

public function getusersAction()
{
    $dbClients = new Application_Model_DbTable_Clients();


    $dbClients->getClientsInfoByName('v');
}

}
```

When I open ajax/getusers function getClientsInfoByName return:

> [{"id":"1","value":"vel vele","label":"vel vele"}]

But why have error message:

> Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
>   Source File: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 1):

That fix my problem:

-before:

```
source: 'ajax/getusers'
```

-now:

```
source: '/ajax/getusers'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to adapt this [example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) with source as un function which call jquery ajax function

```
function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/getusers",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
            featureClass: "P",
            style: "full",
            maxRows: 12,
            name_startsWith: request.term
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                return {
                    label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                    value: item.name
                }
            }));
        }
    });
},
```

I hope it will help you.
Please let me a feedback

Comment: I change my answer. :)

Comment: if your fix is different from my answer, you can write an answer for those who have the same problem? else can you valid my answer to show the solution.